# c++11 expanding parameter pack inside of a lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, parameter-pack

I'm trying to assign a lambda to my std::function that contains 1 call to Test for each type specified in the parameter pack, does anyone know how to do this?

```
template<typename T>
void Test() {
    
}

template<typename ... Ts>
void Expand() {
    std::function<void(void)> func = [Ts] {
        for (const auto& p : { Ts... })
        Test<Ts...>();
    };
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Expand<int, char>();
}
```

I am trying to have this expand to...

```
Test<int>();
Test<char>();
```

Comment: You seem to look for "fold expression" for C++17.

Comment: Do you want to iterate over "types" or "value of a type"?

Comment: i would like to iterate over the types themselves, it should basically expand to...
```
Test<int>();
Test<char>();
```

Comment: You may be looking for something like this: `template<typename ... Ts> void Expand() { int _[] = {(Test<Ts>, 0) ...}; }` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9dYzEe36n). The ugliness is what had to be done in C++11 before fold expressions were invented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<typename ... Ts>
```

`Ts` here represents ***types***. Template parameters are ***types***.

```
[Ts] {
// ...
}
```

A lambda's capture captures ***values***, and ***discrete objects*** rather than ***types***. There's no such thing as a capture of ***types***.

```
for (const auto& p : { Ts... })
```

Range iteration iterates over ***values*** in some container. A braced initialization list is a list ***values*** too, not types.

The major confusion here is the confusion between types and values, in C++.

If the intent is to generate "call to Test for each type specified in the parameter pack", then the simplest solution is to use C++17's fold expression:

```
template<typename ... Ts>
void Expand() {
    std::function<void(void)> func = [] {
        ( Test<Ts>(), ...);
    };
}
```

You tagged your question as C++11, but in the year 2022 it is highly likely that your compiler support C++17 as well.

In the unlikely event that you're limited to C++11, a helper throwaway void function can be used as a crutch:

```
template<typename ...Args>
void ignore_me(Args && ...args)
{
}

template<typename ... Ts>
void Expand() {
    std::function<void(void)> func = [] {
        ignore_me( (Test<Ts>, 0)...);
    };
}
```

Comment: `ignore_me( (Test<Ts>(), 0)...);` would execute functions in unspecified order though. `int dummy[] = {0, (Test<Ts>(), 0)}; static_cast<void>(dummy);` would do the job in order.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged C++11, so if the newest standard version you have in C++11, you'll need to do it recursively.

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct ExpandHelper;

template <>
struct ExpandHelper<> {
  void operator()() {
    // Empty body.
  }
}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct ExpandHelper<T, Ts...> {
  void operator()() {
    Test<T>();
    ExpandHelper<Ts...> rest;
    rest();
  }
}

template <typename... Ts>
void expand() {
  std::function<void(void)> func = [] {
    ExpandHelper<Ts...> helper;
    helper();
  };
}
```

However, if you have access to C++17, you can use [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) with the comma operator, and the result is much shorter.

```
template <typename... Ts>
void expand() {
  std::function<void(void)> func = [] {
    (Test<Ts>, ...)
  };
}
```

Comment: It was bad in C++11, but not *that* bad. `int _[] = {(Test<Ts>, 0) ...};` is the poor-person's fold expression.

Comment: *"you'll need to do it recursively"*, it is one option (Which requires N instantiations (of helper classes), contrary to initializer_list trick).

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T>
void Test() {
    using namespace boost::typeindex;
    std::cout << stl_type_index(typeid(T)).pretty_name() << std::endl;
}

template<typename...Ts>
void Expand() {
    (Test<Ts>(), ...);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Expand<int, char>();
}
```

outputs...

```
int
char
```